# How to Select Min and Max date values in Linq Query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am moving from SQL to Linq and I need some help. I am testing both Linq-to-SQL and Linq-to-Entities. I want to try both to decide which one suits me best. Your help is appreciated. Thanks

What is the correct syntax (in vb.net if possible) to select the minimum date value from a table?

```
Dim mydata As New DataClassesDataContext
Dim myresult = From cv In mydata.T1s
                       Select cv.DATE1, cv.Date2, cv.Datex
myresult=Dump()
```

I have tried I have tried to use

```
Select amin=cv.DATE1.Min(), amax=cv.Date1.Max(), bmin=cv.Date2.Min(), etc....
```

is giving this error `'Min' is not a member of 'Date'`.

The Data That I want to get min and max on is below:

```
IOrderedQueryable<VB$AnonymousType_0<DateTime,DateTime>> (16 items) 

Date1                   Date2
17/Oct/09 12:00:00 AM   23/Oct/09 12:00:00 AM
10/Jan/09 12:00:00 AM   15/Feb/09 12:00:00 AM
27/Mar/09 12:00:00 AM   27/Mar/09 12:00:00 AM
30/May/09 12:00:00 AM   30/May/09 12:00:00 AM
25/Jan/09 12:00:00 AM   25/Mar/09 12:00:00 AM
01/Nov/09 12:00:00 AM   01/Nov/09 12:00:00 AM
21/Feb/09 12:00:00 AM   04/Mar/09 12:00:00 AM
02/Mar/09 12:00:00 AM   09/Mar/09 12:00:00 AM
07/Jul/09 12:00:00 AM   07/Jul/09 12:00:00 AM
27/Sep/09 12:00:00 AM   27/Sep/09 12:00:00 AM
05/Nov/09 12:00:00 AM   05/Nov/09 12:00:00 AM
15/Apr/09 12:00:00 AM   15/Apr/09 12:00:00 AM
08/Jun/09 12:00:00 AM   08/Jun/09 12:00:00 AM
07/Jul/09 12:00:00 AM   07/Jul/09 12:00:00 AM
30/Jul/09 12:00:00 AM   30/Jul/09 12:00:00 AM
04/Nov/09 12:00:00 AM   04/Nov/09 12:00:00 AM
```

Now resolved, but this is not a the perfect solution, it seems that I needed to do a seperate query for each column that requires aggreagate function :

```
Sub Main

Dim mm = (From cv In T1s 
Select Datez = (cv.Date1)).Min()

Dim mm1 = (From cv In T1s 
Select Datez = (cv.Date1)).Max()

Dim mm2 = (From cv In T1s 
Select Datez = (Date2)).Min()

Dim mm3 = (From cv In T1s 
Select Datez = (Date2)).Max()
mm.dump()
mm1.dump()
mm2.dump()
mm3.dump()

End Sub
```

The Results are below

```
10/Jan/09 12:00:00 AM
05/Nov/09 12:00:00 AM
15/Feb/09 12:00:00 AM
05/Nov/09 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

This should work for you

```
//Retrieve Minimum Date
var MinDate = (from d in dataRows select d.Date).Min();

//Retrieve Maximum Date
var MaxDate = (from d in dataRows select d.Date).Max();
```

(From [here](http://www.manojn.com/blog/post/Finding-Min-or-Max-Date-using-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx))

Comment: @Jamasan, I tried this and got the following error: Range variable 'd' hides a variable in an enclosing block or a range variable previously defined in the query expression?

Comment: probably call d in second string as from D2 in datarows select D2.Date

Comment: @Erwin1, it's because you have a different variable called `d` (which is a pretty bad for a local variable, may I say!). Rename that variable or use a different name for parameter, e.g. `row`.

Comment: @gaearon - you'd hate my lambda expressions then, they are always x and y's, i.e, `query.Where( x => x.Name == "Foo" )`

Comment: Tried this and still getting an error Datez is not a member of Date; Dim mm = From DD In (From cv In T1s Select Datez = (cv.Date1)) Select DD.Datez.Min() mm.dump()

Comment: @Jamasan Thanks for the hint. I got it to work, but needed 4 queries.

Comment: @Metro Smurf, `d` is bad for local variable but perfect for lambda parameter name.

Answer (score 44):

If you are looking for the oldest date (minimum value), you'd sort and then take the first item returned. Sorry for the C#:

```
var min = myData.OrderBy( cv => cv.Date1 ).First();
```

The above will return the entire object. If you just want the date returned:

```
var min = myData.Min( cv => cv.Date1 );
```

Regarding which direction to go, re: Linq to Sql vs Linq to Entities, there really isn't much choice these days. Linq to Sql is no longer being developed; Linq to Entities (Entity Framework) is the recommended path by Microsoft these days.

From [Microsoft Entity Framework 4 in Action](http://www.manning.com/mostarda/) (MEAP release) by Manning Press:

> #### What about the future of LINQ to SQL?
>
> It's not a secret that LINQ to
> SQL is included in the Framework 4.0
> for compatibility  reasons. Microsoft
> has clearly stated that Entity
> Framework is the recommended
> technology for data access. In the
> future it will be strongly improved
> and tightly  integrated with other
> technologies while LINQ to SQL will
> only be maintained and little
> evolved.

Comment: @Metro Smurf That will not work because I want to test on multiple date columns in the same table. I will end up with too many sorts.

Comment: @Metro Smurf Thanks for the advise on EF4. Is there syntax difference is putting the Linq-to-SQL or Linq-to-Entities query?

Comment: @Erwin1 - please update your question to reflect what you are trying to achieve, re: the question doesn't mention anything about multiple columns. Regarding EF4 vs Linq to Sql syntax differences, I really don't know as I've never used Linq to Sql; but, I'm gonna go out on a limb and say yes, there will be quite a bit of syntax differences.

Comment: @Metro Smurf  I have updated my question, I hope that you can help. In VB I do not have access to Lambda's.

Comment: Are you returning multiple rows back from the database or just a single row?

Comment: @Metro Smurf I have multiple rows. I am trying to get min() and max() from the columns.

Comment: @Metro Smurf  I managed to resolve this, but I am hoping that there is a more elegant solution out there.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim mydate = from cv in mydata.t1s
  select cv.date1 asc

datetime mindata = mydate[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, but that would not work if I want to get min and max on table that has a number of date columns. i.e i want to do this on say 4 columns.

Comment: sorry, but it says "min" is not a memeber of LINQPad.User.T1s. (Iam testing the code on LinqPAD)