# How can I use LINQ and C# to find the oldest date from 3 different files?

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Select Min and Max date values in Linq Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200877/how-to-select-min-and-max-date-values-in-linq-query)

I'll start by saying my experience with LINQ is very limited. I have been using nested if statements to find the oldest file of 3, and it works just fine. But I'm trying to expand my use of newer technology. A lot of what I read about LINQ gets way over my head pretty fast. Especially when they start using lambda's. So I can get the 3 files dates but how can I grab the oldest among them using LINQ? Or is it even possible? I have the psudo code below.

```
        DateTime file1 = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"c:\test1.txt");
        DateTime file2 = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"c:\test2.txt");
        DateTime file3 = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"c:\test3.txt");

        DateTime[] dates = { file1, file2, file3 };

        var date = from d in dates
                   where d is oldest date
                   select d;
```

Thanks

Comment: I believe you should be able to just use `dates.Min()`

Comment: It's a shame that one receives down-votes with no explanations. If it's because it might be a possible duplicate of the comment mentioned above I'll accept it. But when I found that in my searches I dismissed it because I thought it pertained only to databases. I guess it costs points to learn things.

Comment: I agree, nobody should be penalized for asking a question, especially one with a simple answer.  Linq can be difficult to get used to.  Unless the question is unclear, no downvoting should happen.  And there is no way you would have found the above-referenced post unless you knew about the Min() function already!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var result = dates.Min();
```

is all you need.

Comment: Yes it was! I wasn't aware that a LINQ statement could be so simple. Thanks

Comment: @JimDel But that's the entire point of LINQ to simplify things!

Comment: var MinDate = (from d in dataRows select d.Date).Min();

Answer (score 4):

Use `Min`. Sorta like this:

```
var oldestdate = (from d in dates
                   select d).Min();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime oldest = dates.Min();
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't got any IDE handy, but I think you can use the extension method `dates.Min()`?

You may need to include System.Linq if it's not in your usings explicitly from what I remember.

Comment: `Max` would be the most recent date. (Unless time has suddenly started moving backwards. THE HORROR!)

Comment: Time certainly feels like it's going backwards at 5am :D But grats on catching my typo before my ninja edit!