# how to do Max Aggregation in LINQ query syntax?

Tags: c#, linq, max

LINQ **method syntax**

```
var methodSyntax = VersionControls.Where(x => !x.Removed).Max(x => x.VersionID);
```

LINQ **query syntax**

```
var querySyntax = from x in VersionControls
                  where !x.Removed
                  // how to do Max Aggregation in LINQ query syntax???
                  select x;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSDN documentation says about [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx)

> Query syntax and method syntax are semantically identical, but many people find query syntax simpler and easier to read. Some queries must be expressed as method calls. For example, you must use a method call to express a query that retrieves the number of elements that match a specified condition. **You also must use a method call for a query that retrieves the element that has the maximum value in a source sequence.**

Query syntax can't express everything that method syntax can

check how to combine them for Min and Max [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5200909/1506454)

```
var mixedSyntax = (from x in VersionControls
                  where !x.Removed
                  select x).Max(x => x.VersionID);
```

Comment: @PrzemysławBanaszek, it looks pretty good in method syntax, IMO :)

Comment: Use fluent syntax, that would be more concise, can directly chain Max to Where clause

Answer (score 3):

You have to keep in mind that the `Max()` method will throw an **exception** whenever the source collection is empty. That's why I would chain a [`DefaultIfEmpty(defaultElementValue)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) just before the `Max()` for safety issues. This way, **ASh**'s solution would become :

```
var mixedSyntax = (from x in VersionControls
                  where !x.Removed
                  select x).DefaultIfEmpty(defaultVersionControlObject)
                           .Max(x => x.VersionID);
```